# What is the difference between `set -o emacs` vs `bindkey -e`?

Tags: zsh, line-editor, zle

From what I have seen, both `set -o emacs` and `bindkey -e` are used to modify the behavior of your terminal line editor to emulate `emacs` whereas `set -o vi` and `bindkey -v` are used to emulate `vi` keybindings. Since both `set -o` and `bindkey` seem to do the same thing, I was wondering what the differences between the two were and if there were any differences at all.

It seems like `set -o` works for most shells whereas `bindkey` is a `zle` specific command. Is this the only difference? Also, do they bind the same keys or are there some keys where `set -o` and `bindkey` bind to different operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bindkey -v/-e` is the `tcsh` syntax (a `bindkey` builtin was added to tcsh in 5.19PL2 in 1990), while `set -o vi/emacs` is the ksh syntax (already there in ksh85, probably earlier as ksh had emacs/vi mode at least as far back as 1983).

In `zsh`, `bindkey` was added in 2.0 in 1991 which came with the first version of zle (1.0 the previous version used `readline` borrowed from `bash`).

`zsh`, since the first 1.0 version had `setopt` to set options (in addition to the options passed on the command line like in `csh`/Bourne), while `(t)csh` and `bash` used special variables instead. In 2.0, a `-o` option (both to the interpreter and to the `set` builtin) was added for compatibility with `ksh` (`bash` itself converted its special variables to options set with a new `shopt` builtin in 2.0 in 1996; that's a separate set of options from those set with `set -o` there; `set -o` support added circa 1990).

The `vi` and `emacs` "options" were not [added to zsh until 2003](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2003/msg00392.html) in version 4.1.1 though. The "option" paradigm is not very appropriate for that as when you set the `emacs` option, it disables the `vi` mode.

You'll notice that `zsh -o emacs` and `zsh -o vi` currently don't work properly in that zsh reports `` zsh: invalid module name `zsh/zle' `` on startup (a [bug](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2020/msg00492.html)).

Most shells including `zsh` also select the default editing mode based on the value of the `$EDITOR` and `$VISUAL` environment variables to try and match the line editing mode to the user's editor preference.