# When is it more appropriate to use zsh options vs keybind?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

Context: I was researching how to make my <kbd>tab</kbd> key perform menu completion in zsh. During my search, I found there's two ways (perhaps more) to get this behavior: [options](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html) and/or [keybind](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Completion).

Is choosing one over the other a personal preference, or are there advantages in certain situations? I'm not asking about my particular use case, I'm asking in general: I want to learn when one is the right/wrong tool for the job.

PS: [What is the difference between `set -o` vs `bindkey`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/578888/what-is-the-difference-between-set-o-vs-bindkey) may seem like a duplicate, but it is asking about a specific option/binding. My question is more general.

Comment: Best would be to use the `compinstall` to tune completion initially. If you can't get what you want with that, you can adjust with options, zstyles and possibly even rebind Tab to something different including a widget of your own or of some third party plugin. There's no general recommendation.